# C# winform GUI in Serial comm, If I press enter key, then I want display Shell prompt

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, terminal

C# winform GUI in Serial comm, If I press enter key, then I want display Shell prompt

Hello I am creating a Serial Data Logger

Just create a text box and communicate and receive it in the only one text box.

below is In case of using teraterm

```
.... Serial Logs .....
Device: / $

Device: / $ ls ===> press ls command!!!!

A b c

Device: / $


!!!! caret is located next $ ___
=> Device: /$_
```

How can I implement it upper way?

My DataRecived function is this:

```
Private void DataReceived (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    If (serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        String str = serialPort.ReadLine ();

        Str = str.Trim (). Replace ("\ r \ n", "");

        TbResultBox.AppendText (str + "\ r \ n");
        TbResultBox.ScrollToCaret ();
    }
}
```

If I press enter key after typing in the box, below function is called.

```
Private void tbResultBox_KeyDown (object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    If (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Int maxLines = tbResultBox.Lines.Length;
        If (maxLines> 0)
        {
            String lastLine = tbResultBox.Lines [maxLines - 1];
            If (String.IsNullOrEmpty (lastLine))
                Return;

            Try
            {
                SerialPort.WriteLine (lastLine);
                TbSend.Text = "";
            }
            Catch (Exception ex)
            {
                TbSend.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. How can I implement a terminal like Teraterm?
2. When input data is received during data entry in TextBox, the version that I implemented will be truncated.

While typing cat 123> txt.txt..............

Cat 123>
... Serial Data Recived ...
Txt.txt

If this happens, the input will be txt.txt.
Is there only one way to flush the moment I press the Enter key when I hold the input value in a separate buffer each time the key is pressed?

Comment: Could it be that you are confusing the *terminal* with the behaviour of the ">" operator wich runs in the remote system? The terminal is the terminal (remote input/output), the shell is the shell (where the magic happens).

Comment: I am embedded system driver engineer, so I user Teraterm Serial Port for Uart Log debugging.

If I used communicate with device via UART, then Is it terminal?